# Перевести int в uint16_t и *uint16_t

Tags: c, типы, rsa

Нужно добавить в расширение postgre RSA-шифрование. Обязательно язык С. Нашел на хабре реализацию https://habr.com/ru/post/243425/, код https://github.com/mborisov1/rsa_embedded/. Хочу просто посмотреть, как работает функция `mpi_powm65537`. Как мне перевести к примеру число 43 (int, в последствии придётся то же с char) в uint16_t и *uint16_t? Ума не приложу, как подать на вход, как посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Явное приведение типов в языке Си реализуется с помощью кастов (casts). Для этого необходимо в круглых скобках перед вычисляемым выражением поставить тип к которому необходимо привести выражение. Например так:

```
char ch = 43;
int i = (int)ch;
```

Только надо понимать, что при приведении из типа, который занимает большее количество байт в тип, который занимает меньше, а так-же при приведении из знакового отрицательного в без знаковый могут получаться неадекватные значения. Нюансов много, надо гуглить на запрос "явное преобразование типов в Си". В твоём случае чтобы int привести явно к uint16_t надо выполнить:

```
int i = 43;
uint16_t ui16 = (uint16_t)i;
```

Далее выражение *uint16_t не имеет смысла, так как означает операцию разыменования указателя с именем uint16_t. Но такого имени у указателя не может быть, так как при включении stdint.h это имя уже будет занято именем типа. Произойдёт перегрузка имени и uint16_t для описания типа уже не получится использовать. Короче, можно привести указатель на один тип к указателю на другой так-же кастом, вот пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 43;
    int *p_i; /* pointer to int */
    p_i = &a;
    uint16_t *p_uint16_t; /* pointer to uint16_t */
    p_uint16_t = (uint16_t *)p_i; /* cast from pointer to int to pointer to uint16_t */
    printf("%d", *puint16_t);
    return 0;
}
```